# Prestashop 1.7 - translations missing in back office

Tags: prestashop, prestashop-1.7

I have PrestaShop version 1.7.6.0. When I want to change translations for any of the themes (in Back office), it shows that all the translations are missing, but in my shop, everything is translated.

[image]

What I want is to be able to update translations through the back office.

Similar issue is with for example back office translations where I get the message "There is no translation file available."

Answer (score 1):

I also cannot translate modules in backend and get the error: "There is no translation file available." But everything is translated fine frontend ??